# WebSocket in FastAPI not returning data immediately

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, websocket, fastapi

I have an API for an Whisper AI model. This API starts the transcription for an audio file. When the transcription starts I wanted to get the progress bar on the frontend. I got this using following code.

```py
@app.websocket("/ws/transcribe")
async def transcribe_websocker(websocket: WebSocket):
    
    await websocket.accept()
    process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'ai.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True, shell=False)
    
    while True:
        line = process.stdout.readline()
        if not line:
            break

        # Encode and send the line to the WebSocket client
        encoded_line = line.encode('utf-8')
        print(f"logs: {encoded_line}")
        await websocket.send_text(encoded_line)

    # Close the process and the WebSocket connection
    process.stdout.close()
    process.wait()
    await websocket.close()
```

When I run this code in my windows machine using the command of uvicorn main:app --reload for development it works. It gives the output of the program progress bar as time goes on until the program is finished. I can show the progress bar on the frontend as it progresses.

But when I created a Docker container, the response now only sends the data all at once at the end, when the program is finished executed. Its doesn't send the response in between when the progress is ongoing. The logs are showing in the docker logs at correct times only the websocket results are delayed. The Dockerfile used:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

WORKDIR /python-docker

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install git -y

RUN pip3 install fastapi
RUN pip3 install "uvicorn[standard]"
RUN pip3 install -U git+https://github.com/jianfch/stable-ts.git
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg
RUN pip3 install moviepy
RUN pip3 install streaming_form_data
RUN pip3 install websockets

COPY . .

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

#COPYING MODELS
COPY base.pt /root/.cache/whisper/base.pt

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

Screenshots:
[image] Docker Logs

[image] Postman Websocket response

As you can see the docker logs (screenshot 1) are coming at correct time with time interval in between, which means the print statement `print(f"logs: {encoded_line}")` is working correctly, but the `await websocket.send_text(encoded_line)` statement isn't. As it can be seen from postman response picture (screenshot 2), all of the text is received when websocket connection closes at 11:48:43.
I suspect the websocket is buffering the responses and sends at the end like I was experiencing with python when there was no `ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` in the Dockerfile.
I have tried sending using the `websocket.send_bytes(line)` and `websocket.write_buffer_size = 0` to overcome this but the problem remains.

Comment: Does this bug reproduces with something simple, like `await asyncio.sleep(1)` inside `while True` loop?